# Composition of two transport maps and pushforward operator

Tags: optimal-transport

Given two absolutely continuous probability measures $\mu,\sigma \in \mathcal P_2(\mathbb R^n)$ and two maps $T_1, T_2$ such that $$(T_1 \circ T_2)_\#\sigma =\mu$$
where $(\cdot)_{\#}$ denotes the pushforward operator. I saw that it is a general property that

$$(T_1 \circ T_2)_\#\sigma={T_1}_{\#}({T_2}_{\#}\sigma)$$

How can one make sense of this or see this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, for a probability $\mu$ and a map $T$, one defines
$$T_\# \mu(A) := \mu(T^{-1}(A)),$$
for a measurable set $A$, right?

Then, in your notations:
$$\begin{align*}
(T_1 \circ T_2)_\#\sigma(A) & = \sigma((T_1\circ T_2)^{-1}(A)) \\
& = \sigma(T_2^{-1}(T_1^{-1}(A))) \\
& = (T_{2\#}\sigma)(T_1^{-1}(A)) \\
& = T_{1\#}(T_{2\#}\sigma)(A).
\end{align*}$$
That is,
$$(T_1 \circ T_2)_\#\sigma = T_{1\#}(T_{2\#}\sigma).$$

Comment: And then, formally, wouldn't it be

$${T_2}_{\#}\sigma(T_1^{-1}(A))$$ instead of $$({T_2}_{\#}\sigma)(T_1^{-1}(A))$$, since $\sigma$ is applied onto the measurable set?

Comment: However, we would then get $${T_2}_\#{T_1}_\#\sigma(A)$$, so I guess I must have got something wrong

Comment: I don't quite get you. Note that, given a probability $\sigma$ and a map $T$, then $T_\#\sigma$ is a new probability. So $(T_{2\#}\sigma)(T_1^{-1}(A))$ can be read as the $T_{2\#}\sigma$-probability of the measurable set $T_1^{-1}(A)$. What would it mean, for you, the expression $T_{2\#}\sigma(T^{-1}(A))$? To me, they mean the same: a probability acting on a measurable set. I just added the parenthesis to clarify.